# facebook show recommend count on mouse over

Tags: facebook, addthis

I am using Addthis plugin. I have an "F" icon on the page. I want it to work as recommend functionality.
is there anyway to do following
if somebody click on F, it should work as recommend is clicked, and on move over this F, it should just show the Count of recommend

**we do not want to show standard recommend box with count**

**Secondly question**, when i click on any like button it also show another Share Popup, but even even if i cancel this popup, still my timeline show i have recommended that particular page.. then what is use of that popup.

Comment: shouldn't you be asking the AddThis developer this question?

Comment: @lgy there are lots of questions on AddThis on stackoverflow, thats why i asked here. there is also Addthis category.

Comment: Fair enough, i'm not familiar with addthis, and this sounded like a feature request or 'how can i do X' rather than a specific question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Facebook Dialog JavaScript](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to show a Share dialog for a custom button. Or use the [Send Dialog button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) to create a private share dialog.

The "Comment Box" on the Like Button is optional, it's not required. If you enter a comment, it adds it to the Like post that appears on your timeline. But you can still like a page without entering a comment. A Like with a comment appears more prominent on the user's timeline.